# How to filter through textfield in models in django

Tags: django, filter, textfield

I am trying to create a small search feature within my django project and i need to filter through my data

My models are all in textfield formats, and when i try to use .filter() to search for what i want, i get an error saying that "instance of textfield has no filter member" on visual code studio. is there any way to work around this?

```
#My Model
class api_data(models.Model):
    data_source = models.TextField()
    brief_description_of_data = models.TextField()
    datasets_available = models.TextField()
    brief_description_of_datasets = models.TextField()
    country = models.TextField()
    api_documentation = models.TextField()

#what I'm trying to do
def index(request):
    query = request.Get.get('q')
    if query:
        queryset_list = api_data.datasets_available.filter(Q(datasets_available__icontains=query))
```

Comment: there is no `title` field in model `api_data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `filter` the model object not the field

```
 queryset_list = api_data.objects.filter(Q(datasets_available__icontains=query))
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/

Comment: oh yes thanks for pointing that out! but it still doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: You shouldn't be getting same error message anymore. What are trying to achieve now.

Comment: i want to filter through the datasets_available to find the ones that match my query. I still get the "instance of textfield has no filter member" error

Comment: And you're using this `api_data.objects.filter(Q(datasets_available__icontains=query))` to query?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `Q`:
this will work:

```
queryset_list = api_data.objects.filter(datasets_available__icontains=query)
```